# Faster way to convert integer array to string vector

Tags: string, vector, integer

So I have a vector with n one digit elements. I want to make m digit numbers using these elements. m and n will be given by user.

For example:

If the original vector is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, I want the new vector to be {012,345,678}.

So instead of 9 one digit elements, we now have 3 three-digit elements. Once again, the user gives the value of n and m.

Now I have been able to do this by converting the elements to a string and appending them. But the problem is that the array size needs to be very large (about 3 million long).

When I use my logic for this long value, it takes ages to compile. This is what I have currently.

```
vector<string> list_generator(int *array,int m, int combinations)
{
string ryan, temp;
stringstream aStream;
vector<string> lexicographic;   

while (next_permutation(array, array + m))
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i = i + m)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = i; j < m+ 1; j++)
        aStream << array[i];
        temp = aStream.str();
        ryan.append(temp);
        aStream.str("");
    }
    lexicographic.push_back(ryan);
    ryan.clear();
}
return (lexicographic);
```

}

Is there a faster way to do this.

Comment: why are you adding an array and an int? or, should this be array.length + m?

Comment: That is how the next_permutation syntax works. It is a C++ function.

Comment: Where does `std::next_permutation` factor into this? I don't see why you'd want to use that here.